# Link title to external link instead of permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to get the same effect as the plugin [Pages Link To](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/) where the title of the post is linked to an external link. The reason I don't want to use the plugin is the link is generated dynamically when the post is saved, but I'm unable to update the the permalink of the post with the external link.

Below is my code in functions.php:

```
function savepost( $post_id ) {
    if( $_POST['post_type'] == 'books' ){
    $genre = strip_tags(get_field('genre'));
    $author = strip_tags(get_field('author'));
    $extlink = "http://www.".$genre."/".$author.".com";

     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'extlink', $extlink);

     $url = strip_tags(get_field('extlink',$post));
     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_link', $url);
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'savepost' );
```

i m trying another method in which i assigned a template to the post so that when the post loads it redirects to the link but it doesn't redirect

my code

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: post Redirection Template
 */
get_header();

$redirecturl = strip_tags(get_field('extlink',$post));

wp_redirect($redirect_url);

get_sidebar();
get_footer();

?>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do, is insert the external link as a custom field in the post editor, then display the custom field value in place of `the_permalink()`. You could use a plugin such as [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to grab the URL from the custom field.

EDIT 1: More clarification using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin as an example. The field name for this example is `url`.

You should use this wherever you want the custom permalink to appear throughout your site, such as in your `archive.php`, `category.php`, etc. Replace the code that looks something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo the_permalink();"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

with this:

```
<?php
$value = get_field( "url" );
if( $value ) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $value;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="<?php echo the_permalink();"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

EDIT 2: Clarifying additional information.

You can add a function to the `header.php` of your theme that checks if the url is set, then redirects to the external link that way, if your user goes directly to the permalink, it will still redirect them. In fact, you could use this code without using the above code to display the external link.

```
<?php
$value = get_field( "url" );
if( $value ) { 
header('Location: '.$value);
die();
} else {} ?>
```

**Warning**: make sure to use this code before any HTML (or text) has been passed to the browser, or it will not work correctly.

Comment: i updated the code and tried what u said but it doesn't replace the default permalink..plz correct the code i can't seem to figure out whats wrong

Comment: Where are you updating your code? In the above functions.php?

Comment: That is your problem. You need to be modifying the theme files where you want the external link to appear. I'll update my question with a little more detail to help you.

Comment: the code u gave will echo the url correctly but on the archive pageor the theme frontend where the title is listed becuase thts where the checking will be done...what i am trying to do is even if someone click on the post permalink directly it shud take them to the ext link only.

Comment: meaning by default say the post or the title's url is http://mydomain.com/post=1 so if someone knows the post url even if they type it in it shud tke them to the external url redirect them basically

Comment: That isn't going to work, see the warning at the end of my post. If you redirect before the header is loaded, or inside the `header.php` itself, before text or HTML is sent to the browser, it will work. After HTML/text has been sent to the browser will not work. Also, make sure to add exit; after you redirect.

Comment: just one more thing is it possible to hide or grey out a custom field in ACF

Comment: You can use conditional logic with ACF. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/creating-a-field-group/

Comment: i want the field to be present but hidden or greyed out using conditional logic it removes the field totally

Comment: @user3449454 it might be possible, but I'm not sure how to do it. Sorry! Try opening another question on the WordPress Development community and see if anyone there can help!

Comment: cud uhelp with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618470/execute-query-on-multiple-parameters too plz...thanx in advance