# How do I execute a WP_Query with multiple arguments?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to do a WP_Query where I want the loop to execute only if the post type is books and genre is the text in $genre. I keep getting an error as it displays all the posts in the books post type instead of the particular genre required.

I have tried this:

```
<?php
$genre ="suspense";
$args = array('post_type' => 'books','genre' => $genre);     
        //Define the loop based on arguments     
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );   
        //Display the contents   
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

?>
```

Comment: So you want the loop to only display posts that are both books and genre? You cannot have a post in two different post types. Are you looking for WP_Query to return posts from the 'books' post type, with the category of 'suspense'?

Comment: books is a posttype and genre is a custom field in that books

Comment: are the genres actually set with values in mysql? Your syntax is correct and this should be working according to the docs for wp_query. So maybe you have a mismatch with the genre values?

Comment: 'genre' is a custom field that has values in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the value of the custom field and perform a `meta_query`. Try the following code:

```
<?php
$genre ="suspense";
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'books',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'genre',
            'value' => $genre,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();   
?>
```

Read more on the WordPress Codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.